# How to fix this error 'Swift Language Version' in Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

Could you help me?

How to fix this error?

> Xcode's output: 
>   ↳
>       === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>       The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can
>   be set in the build settings editor.
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
>   application on iPhone 8.

yes, already tried this.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'  # add this
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

but not working for me..

Does anyone know any other way?

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Originally, I used git to bring it at once, but when I moved the dart files one by one, the error was disappeared. Thank you for your comments.